# Do I need to have the .net Framework installed in order to run c#/c code through NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, interop

I have a simple demand to run c#/c++ code through NodeJS?

I have concluded that (edgejs library) allows us to run .net code in JavaScript so my question is
**do I need to have the .net framework installed on the computer that hosts WEBApp through NodeJS?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run C# or any other managed code with [edge.js](https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge/blob/master/README.md) you need to install the .net framework version 4.5

This is listed in the **What you need** section of the readme for edgejs on github

> Edge.js: run .NET and Node.js code in-process
>   [What you need](https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge/blob/master/README.md#what-you-need)